# Extracting value from ResponseText

Tags: javascript, json, rest

Need a help with the below code. it's working just fine, but I need to extract and present only one value from the return info, for example how I can extract only the "nextRun" value from:

```js
function CallWebAPI() {
  var token_ = "*Token*"
  var request_ = new XMLHttpRequest();        
  request_.onreadystatechange=function(){
      
    if (request_.readyState===4){
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = request_.responseText;
    }
  }
  request_.open("GET", "https://192.168.33.42:4443/v1/Jobs", true);
  request_.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','');
  request_.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  request_.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache'); 
  request_.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token_);
  request_.send();
}
```

```html
<h1 id="demo">Must be here</h1>        
<button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=CallWebAPI()">Get Token</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be problem with the url that the data is stored. Check this out:

```js
    function CallWebAPI() {

     var token_ = "*Token*"
     var request_ = new XMLHttpRequest();        
    
      request_.onreadystatechange=function(){
     
       
       console.log(request_.readyState === 4) // readyState is false
     
      if (request_.readyState===4){
     
          console.log(request_.responseText)
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = request_.responseText;
       }
      }
      request_.open("GET", "https://192.168.33.42:4443/v1/Jobs", true);
      request_.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','');
      request_.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      request_.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache'); 
      request_.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token_);
            request_.send();
    } 

 

document.getElementById("checkAllTopicCheckBoxes").addEventListener ("click", CallWebAPI, false);
```

```html
<h1 id="demo">Must be here</h1>
 <button id="checkAllTopicCheckBoxes"> Get Token</button>
```

It looks like the real problem is that request_.readyState does not equal to 4.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, the code working just fine 100%, but I want to present only one value from the return - not all the body. For example, I wish to run a search to find "name" and present it on HTML.